# Need to create a public READONLY note taking app for any users READ and Search

Tags: open-source

I need to create a public READONLY note taking app for any users READ and Search without any login.
Like a website viewed by anyone...

However highlight and other features are good in note taking apps

No EDIT/DELETE is allowed to any users..Just read only.

Please advise is any software is already matches this or how to develop this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more details about your use case? With your very sparse description, I can think of a simple reason why such an app would never exist: if anonymous users are supposed to "highlight and other features" (that means incorporate some input of their own), then the app would rapidly fill up with spam or the like and then become useless for its original intention. I might be mistaken in my understanding, but then that might be because your description is not sufficiently detailed.

Comment: This sounds just like an ordinary pdf reader app. Read, annotate, but can't [trivially] change the original text.

Comment: Assume i have 3000 note files....I want to make it as searcheable and viewable and readable to others BUT none should delete or edit my notes. I am the owner....I want to publish them with easy navigation .....I feel note taking app is good in terms of search, highlight and easy navigation...However there is no READONLY option in any note taking app to publish

Comment: Assume i want to publish newspaper text from 1995 to 2023 -- title would be on left, content would be on right...a search bar would be on left top --- common pattern in any note taking app....but none of them should delete my newspaper content...highlight is not user higlight...it is our server highlight when user searches for a keyword

Comment: Note taking is a misnomer.  You want a publishing app or software.

Comment: app or software or both

Comment: Please advise @RohitGupta

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like these

1. **[MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)**

> The MediaWiki software is used by tens of thousands of websites and thousands of companies and organizations. It powers Wikipedia and also this website. MediaWiki helps you collect and organize knowledge and make it available to people. It's powerful, multilingual, free and open, extensible, customizable, reliable, and free of charge.

2. **[DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki)**

> DokuWiki is a simple to use and highly versatile Open Source wiki software that doesn't require a database. It is loved by users for its clean and readable syntax. The ease of maintenance, backup and integration makes it an administrator's favorite. Built in access controls and authentication connectors make DokuWiki especially useful in the enterprise context and the large number of plugins contributed by its vibrant community allow for a broad range of use cases beyond a traditional wiki.

I am not associated by either.  But I am actively considering using one or the other.